# Why is left style ignored?

Tags: html, css, developer-tools

I have logo on page in the following code

```
<h1 class="site-title">
   <a class="logo custom-logo" href="url" title="Go to Site"> 
      <img alt="Site" height="136" src="url" width="298"> 
   </a> 
</h1>
```

I have added `left` attribute to `logo` style

```
.logo {
   display: inline-block;
   line-height: 1;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

this

```
left: 400px;
```

But it is ignored. Chrome `Developer tools` shows this style is active, but the image is displayed at the zero distance from left side of browser window.

Why?

Comment: Because it is still in the flow of the document, set it to `position: relative;` if you want it to abide by the left

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for a `left, top, bottom, right` value to take effect, the item must be positioned.

Add either `position: absolute` or `position: relative` depending on your needs.

Absolute will position it relative to it's closest positioned parent.

Relative will position relative to itself.

Answer (score 1):

you can either side the position:relative or set the left padding to be 400px

```
position:relative;
left: 400px;
```

or

```
padding-left:400px
```